# Mocking setTimeout with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, settimeout

I have a website made with React.JS that is continuously emitting events for everything [and nothing] that is happening. For example, users typed something in the form, emit an event. Users set focus on a field and do not do anything for some time, we again emit an event. The idea is to understand customers' behavior.

I have a button what used to work as `<Button onClick={(e)=>handler(e)}/>`. I had to debounce the button and change it to `<Button onClick={(e)=>setTimeout(handler(e), 1000)}/>`. Otherwise, users did not understand what was happening.

Now, I am trying to adjust the tests written as:

```
  it('displays similar listings', async () => {
    const renderResult = renderVdp(renderParams);

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    await waitFor(async () => {
      expect(renderResult.getAllByText('2017 BMW M3')).toHaveLength(4);
    });
  });
```

I was able to keep the original tests working by adding the `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));` before relevant tests. Without it, tests receive the next emitted event, which is not the event emitted as a response to clicking on the button.

I would like to use jest timer mocking or something similar, instead of actually introducing delays inside my tests. I have tried using `jest.useFakeTimers()`, but it does not work as I need it to. My expects are failing.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Once you use fake timers, you control when to run them.
Try to run them after you render:

```
it('displays similar listings', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    const renderResult = renderVdp(renderParams);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    expect(renderResult.getAllByText('2017 BMW M3')).toHaveLength(4);
  });
```

If that's not working, you can always use a more "aggressive" mock:

```
global.setTimeout = jest.fn(cb => cb());
```

I would do it in the test setup `beforeEach` / `beforeAll` and rollback to original setTimeout in the test teardown `afterEach` / `afterAll`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Neither is working. `global.setTimeout` raises an error - `Type 'Mock<any, [cb: any]>' is not assignable... Property '__promisify__' is missing in type 'Mock<any, [cb: any]>' but required in type 'typeof setTimeout'.` and  `jest.useFakeTimers()` and `jest.runAllTimers();` is not working either. I tried `advanceTimer` too.

Comment: This is a Typescript error. I'm not sure how the signature of setTimeout is defined there. You can always add @ts-ignore to see if it's working.

Comment: If you don't have an await and you are using fakeTimers, I don't think you still need to use async.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell how the test should look like if I can't see the code.

If your component works a little bit like this:

```js
const SetTimeoutComponent = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleButtonClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setContent([
        '2017 BMW M3',
        '2017 BMW M3',
        '2017 BMW M3',
        '2017 BMW M3'
    ])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(e)=>setTimeout(() => handleButtonClick(e), 1000)}>
        Set timeout with state update
      </button>
      <div>
        {content.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

then you can test it as follows:

```js
it('displays similar listings', async () => {
  render(<TestedComponent />);
  const setTimeoutButton = screen.getByRole('button');

  jest.useFakeTimers();
  fireEvent.click(setTimeoutButton);
  act(() => {
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });
  expect(screen.getAllByText('2017 BMW M3')).toHaveLength(4);

  jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

You can check more in [my post](https://marek-rozmus.medium.com/mocking-settimeout-with-jest-3fd6b8fa6307).

Comment: If you don't have an await and you are using fakeTimers, I don't think you still need to use async.